# What would be the cost of bandwidth on google cloud platforms if i make a video calling app?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, video-streaming, google-compute-engine, http-live-streaming, bandwidth

Zoom provides video streaming services, and I made one of my own and considering deploying it on google compute, it says the bandwidth will cost **$110** for **1TB** if I use it in a month. The cost is pretty much high if we charge a fee like zoom.

If I want to deploy such service it would cost very high considering only bandwidth. What will be an estimate if i had **100 meetings** rooms open and in each meeting room **50 participants** are there , What would be the estimated cost if they are active for **8 hours** per day?

What will be approximate **bandwidth** they would use considering variable quality of stream, may be **240p**, **360p** or **720p**, considering on the user side they are able to receive the full quality of stream?

Is google calculates egress on the basis of computed data or the amount of data sent to the user regardless of computation of data or a direct download of file?

Person having a good knowledge of google compute please answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question seeks opinions that will vary and is off topic. I voted to close. Read this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google simply calculates the egress or the data sent from the VM considering what goes out of the VM whether it is processed or not.

The price of egress is roughly **$0.12/GB**, for latest rates visit **gcloud pricing calculator**.

The egress totally depends upon the number of users downloading or accessing the data on the VM.

So suppose at 240p 40kbps of data is needed on the client side, so

considering **100 rooms** with **50 persons** each comes to be **5000 clients** connected to the VM at an instance.

So, conducting a meeting which lasts **8 hours a day**, the egress from the VM would be

```
5000*(40kbps)*(8*3600 seconds)
= 5*40*8*3600 MB
= 5760000 MB
= 5760 GB
```

And the cost of such egress would be

```
5760 GB * $0.12/GB
= $691.2
```

So, if you have such **high bandwidth usage** and you want a **cheaper option** try using **digital ocean**, their bandwidth is **cheaper than gcloud and AWS**

Answer (score 0):

There are to many variables to be able to calculate a price, or even egress, however there is a tool available for platform pricing that you can use based on estimates. [Cloud Platform Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) Hopefully this will be able to give you the information you are seeking

Comment: I tried that but my question is egress is what goes out simply, or it is cpu computed data which goes out.

Comment: As I have mentioned before, there are to many variables, costs are calculated depending on how your deployment is made. The best recommendation I can give is to use the free trail and attempt small scale tests, and this will give you a good idea of exactly how deployment plays a role in costs. https://cloud.google.com/free